# Select top record by group without order by

Tags: sql, teradata

My source table looks like this

```
cust_id  cust_name
1        John Smith
1        John K Smith
2        Mary B Snow
2        Mary Snow
```

and I would like to return

```
cust_id  cust_name
1        John Smith
2        Mary B Snow
```

where one cust_name value is not preferred over another; I just want one row per cust_id, with an arbitrary cust_name attached.

I'm using

```
select cust_id, cust_name from customers
qualify 1 = row_number() over (partition by cust_id order by cust_name desc)
```

but this has the weakness that I can't use it in a subquery due to the `order by` clause.

Is there a way I can do this without the (conceptually unnecessary) ordering?

Comment: Shouldn't that query return Mary Snow, not Mary B Snow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select cust_id, min(cust_name) 
from customers 
group by cust_id
```

Comment: This seems like a pretty dumb question now--I had no idea min/max were legal for text fields. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this will return single row per customer id `group by cust_name` groups entries based on name field, but not id.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `SELECT NULL` in  `ORDER BY` clause. So that it wont change the order and Row_Number will work as expected

Try this

```
SELECT cust_id, cust_name FROM
(
  SELECT cust_id, cust_name ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION  BY cust_id ORDER BY  (SELECT NULL)) RN
  FROM customers
)Tmp WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: It works, but still very slow compared to straight select (which I think the idea was to be competitive with, speed-wise).

Answer (score 0):

If ordering is not required, just run this:

```
SELECT cust_id, MAX(cust_name)
FROM customers
GROUP BY cust_id
```

Comment: Ah...thanks you meant aggregation function call is missing.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
select cust_id, 
min(cust_name) as cust_name
from customers 
group by cust_id
```